Bind9 limit the Answer RRs in a standart query response
I am looking for a way to restrict the number of RR answers my client receives from the Bind9 DNS Server, does anyone know how I could do that?
I did already try serverl different options such as adding the minimal-responses to yes and/or         minimal-any to yes. adding the max-udp-size to the options but it does not really have any effect in limiting the nunber of RR Answers:
Domain Name System (response)
Transaction ID: 0x2401
Flags: 0x8500 Standard query response, No error
Questions: 1
**Answer RRs: 17**
Authority RRs: 0
Additional RRs: 0
Queries
    chain.randompage.net: type AAAA, class IN
        Name: chain.randompage.net
        [Name Length: 23]
        [Label Count: 3]
        Type: AAAA (IPv6 Address) (28)
        Class: IN (0x0001)
Answers
    chain.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host1.randompage.net
    host1.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain1.randompage.net
    chain1.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host2.randompage.net
    host2.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain2.randompage.net
    chain2.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host3.randompage.net
    host3.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain3.randompage.net
    chain3.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host4.randompage.net
    host4.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain4.randompage.net
    chain4.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host5.randompage.net
    host5.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain5.randompage.net
    chain5.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host6.randompage.net
    host6.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain6.randompage.net
    chain6.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host7.randompage.net
    host7.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain7.randompage.net
    chain7.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host8.randompage.net
    host8.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname chain8.randompage.net
    chain8.randompage.net: type CNAME, class IN, cname host9.randompage.net 

I would like to get a single answer RR back from the DNS server. So that for each FQDN a new query is triggerd from the client.

Do you control the authoritative name server that you want to query? The resolver cannot limit the number of answers that it wants to receive. Your application will have to do that. In case you do not have access to the source code of the client application, you can build your own resolver that sits in between the clients and the authoritative servers. Perhaps it is better do explain why you want this behaviour.
